# Change Apache root directory to another location

Tags: php, apache-2.4, http-status-code-403, local, forbidden

I'm trying to change the default Apache root location `/var/www/html` to `/mnt/datos/mylocation`. I also tried to /home/[MY USER]/mylocation, thinking it was related to mounted partition permissions.

- I tried using `root:root`, `www-data:www-data` and `[MY USER]` as `/mnt/datos/mylocation`'s owner,
- I tried multiple locations (bc I had doubts about permissions).
- I created an empty .htaccess file.
- I even gave 777 to everything (just to test, I know it's bad).
- Sites are enabled in Apache config.
- Apache was restarted to apply changes.

when I load `localhost` or `NNNNN.local` it shows:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

**WHAT IS MISSING???**

My current files are as following:

**/etc/apache2/apache.conf**

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName NNNNN.local
    ServerAlias NNNNN.local
    DocumentRoot /mnt/datos/mylocation
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is SELinux enabled? Check for errors: `journalctl -xe`. SELinux will, by default, prevent httpd from accessing files outside of the standard `/var/www/` path.

Comment: I got this:   `$ sestatus   SELinux status:disabled` ;    `$ getenforce Disabled`

Comment: Did you apply the chmod to the top directory as well, or just the files ?

Comment: This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/337874/change-apache-document-root-folder-to-secondary-hard-drive

Comment: @SBO applied it to everything up to  tthe filess I  need to serve.

Comment: @asktyagi thanks, but n fact I did followed thee instructions on that question too.